# Proportional devision of months from the list of given months

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I am given a list of months (`TOTAL_NUM_MONTHS`) and from this list I need to select only 12 months proportionally. I have following algorithm up to now:

```
IF TOTAL_NUM_MONTHS<12 THEN
   STEP = 1
ELSE IF (TOTAL_NUM_MONTHS % 12 == 0) THEN
   STEP = TOTAL_NUM_MONTHS / 12
ELSE
   STEP = ???
```

So, if total number of months is less then 12 I will select all of them, and if it is divisible to 12 then I will select them with a step equal to `TOTAL_NUM_MONTHS/12`.

**Question:** What to do if the total number of months is not divisible to 12 ? How to calculate the step in order to select 12 months from the given list of months proportionally ?

Comment: Pls leave a comment with a reason for down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should take a step of variable length for each iteration, something like:

`step(i) = step(i-1) + NUM_MONTHS/12.0`, `step(0) = 0.0` [note: step(i) is a floating point number and not an integer]

And use `floor(step(i))` to chose element. [assuming here `NUM_MONTHS > 12`]

`i` is the step's number. You chose `a[i] = floor(step(i))` as your i'th element for each `0 <= i < 12`

The idea is to create a monotonically increasing function that distributes uniformly. It doesn't get more uniform then `NUM_MONTHS/12` size, with floating points. So, you calculate it with floating points - and then use `floor(step(i))` to get the integer out of it.

This method ensures 2 things:

1. No element is chosen twice [because `NUM_MONTHS/12 > 1`]
2. The maximum difference between every two steps is `1`.

Also note that if `NUM_STEPS % 12 == 0` this method decays to your `else if` and behave the same.

Comment: what is i here? Could you explain your point of view a little bit more please?

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: I editted and clarified a few things. Let me know if there is something you still misunderstand in this answer.